# @configurable Vaadin app controller not reinjecting after tomcat restart

Tags: spring, vaadin

I am using a @configurable annotated Vaadin controller together with my Spring context, and it is working fine - except when I need to restart Tomcat, and the sessions are deserialized. Then I get this for my Vaadin app:

org.springframework.beans.factory.wiring.BeanConfigurerSupport BeanFactory has not been set on BeanConfigurerSupport: Make sure this configurer runs in a Spring container. Unable to configure bean of type [web.vaadin.ui.BackOfficeApplication]. Proceeding without injection.

I am thinking that this can be because the vaadin app is reserializing before the spring bean factory has a chance to?

(I am using CTW - aspectj and Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE)

Note:

It seems in the log that these errors come before the "Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started". How can it be that the beans are being autowired before the context initialization is started?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on (de)serialization with Spring and Tomcat, and this is not an answer but might be a workaround.

If `BackOfficeApplication` is your Vaadin application then there is an alternative to using `@Configurable` on that class. Instead, create a per-Vaadin Application Spring application context XML file and add this to it to cause your `BackOfficeApplication` instances to be autowired, etc.:

```
<bean id="backOfficeApplication"
  class="org.dellroad.stuff.vaadin.ContextApplication"
  factory-method="get"/>
```

In general, `@Configurable` can be more troublesome than normal bean wiring because they require the configuration to occur at object construction rather than allowing the bean factory to do the wiring later on, where it may be better able to detect loops, enforce ordering, etc.

Ideally normal bean wiring should be used for singletons that are initialized once at the beginning of the application and `@Configurable` should be used for "on the fly" beans created randomly during normal operation.